# Angular guard needs to set state, but can't easily reset it

Tags: angular

I am trying to write some code contained in my guard which checks some auth information and based on it causes an angular component to appear "you are not authorised", and then fade out.
This works, but only the first time the user tries to navigate to an unauthorised rout. I would like it to work every time, and I believe the problem is that I can' reset the state inside the guard.

**error component**

```
<div class="warning error-message"   *ngIf="auth$ | async">You are not authorised to access this function</div>


export class AuthmessageComponent {

  public auth$;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
      this.auth$ = this.authService.auth$;
     
  }
```

**service code**

```
export class AuthService {
    public auth$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    constructor() {
    }
```

**Guard code**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.authService.auth$.next(false); //remove message component, this isn't working
    if (!this.isAdmin){            
        console.log("Your user role prevents access to this page");
        this.authService.auth$.next(true); //show message
    }
    return this.isAdmin;
```

I think the problem is that I am trying to reset the component by making it false and then true, but the ngIf statement is only responding to the true.

Is there another way I could get this to work other than doing the state reset on the page that does the route navigation? I am trying to keep the code contained in the guard if possible.

Comment: `*ngIf="condition"` renders the block only if the condition evaluates to true. For cases needing false condition, we need the `else` also: `*ngIf=condition; else #elseBlock`. [Many examples can be found in the official doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description).

Comment: I only want the message if it evaluates to true. I was trying to set it to false again to trigger the change detection

Comment: Are you sure the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` block exists in the root component's template? It should be present to have `canActivate()` triggered upon every route change.